# Collapsing Toolbar with NavigationDrawer toggle button not showing

Tags: android, toolbar, navigation-drawer, android-togglebutton

so im building android application in my main activity im using collapse toolbar with navigation drawer but the tuggle button for the navigationDrawer not showing.
so i need a  way to make the toggle appear specially when toolbar fully collapsed

this is my content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.infinity.dev.nearby.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/france"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            style="@style/AppTheme"

            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView...>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer"
            app:itemTextColor="#212121"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the app_bar_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main2" />
```

this is the code used in main_activity.java:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.MyToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =  (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("My Country");
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);                    

collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));
```

[image of toolbar before collapse:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDO2K.jpg)

[image of toolbar after Collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7quKu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reason for that, do one thing try to click on place of toggle button, if it opens drawer means your toggle is not visible due to theme style of your so you can change colorof your toggle from theme, otherwise this one:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">


   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/france"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



 This might be useful for you ,try to use this one
```